# Inserting Foreign Key into a table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sqlyog

I am trying to insert a foreign key into a table i just created. 2 tables involved.

1st Table created:

```
CREATE TABLE trip (
tripID  INT(10) NOT NULL,
startTime   TIME,
endTime     TIME,
tripDate    DATE,
price       VARCHAR(5),
databaseID  INT(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(tripID)
);
```

2nd Table created:

```
CREATE TABLE dataBaseStorage (
databaseID  INT(10)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,                    
location        VARCHAR(40)
);
```

After adding values into both tables, I ran:

```
ALTER TABLE trip
ADD FOREIGN KEY(databaseID)
REFERENCES databasestorage(databaseID)
```

And i have also tried:

```
ALTER TABLE trip
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_databaseID FOREIGN KEY(databaseID)
REFERENCES databasestorage(databaseID)
```

Both methods provides the same output of 'Error code:1452' - cannot add or update child row: a foreign key constraint fails. All i am trying to do is to show 'databaseID' in the trip table where the value comes from the primary key in the dataBaseStorage table. A solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any rows in either table before the `ALTER` ?

Comment: @Drew As i posted it, yeah it had rows in the tables, however i've tried `ALTER` before inserting the rows. Once i've done that, it works.. but after trying to insert the row into the table afterwards, it returns the same error as when there were rows in the table. I'm inserting the rows by using         `INSERT INTO trip(tripID, startTime, endTime, tripDate, price)
 VALUES('101', '20:20:00', '20:40:00', '2016-10-22', '$5.25')`

Comment: It's pretty simple. The `ALTER` to succeed must have all the conditions met for keys in place / datatypes / collation if relevant. But it must also have either (A) no rows, or (B) pre-existing data that supports the FK constraint request. Otherwise a generic and sometimes useless to decipher (to newbies) Error 1452 results

Comment: @Drew I've tried to make sure that there is no preexisting data and no rows when applying `ALTER`. It works but i'm having trouble adding the values into the table where adding it to the table was not a problem before applying `ALTER`.

Comment: well that is a good problem to have and not related to this question anymore. Post on pastebin (and share the url) of (A) `show create table dataBaseStorage` and `show create table trip` and (B) the insert statements that lead up to a failure. That I can help you will. But this question is over as I see it

Comment: @Drew Sorry, i've not used pastebin before and i'm not too sure what you are asking for, but i've listed all the codes that i've used and commented on them to showcase the steps that i've taken. http://pastebin.com/9g94h1zb

Comment: Right you have listed them and we determined it worked fine but your data is a problem. I am seemingly done helping here. In other words, this original question is resolved.

Comment: I cannot because you can't show me the data steps. I have other questions to deal with elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your capitalization is off. You used camel case when you created the "dataBaseStorage" table, but you're using lowercase to reference it.

Comment: The first method you tried (without add constraint) should work.

Comment: unfortunately after trying to implement your solution, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: what i've tried is, fixed my capitalisation error, and ran:

Comment: `ALTER TABLE trip
ADD FOREIGN KEY(databaseID)
REFERENCES databasestorage(databaseID)` 

without adding in values to the table yet. However, after adding the foreign key, once i try to add values into the table. It returns:  Error Code : 1452
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`s3483099`.`trip`, CONSTRAINT `trip_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`databaseID`) REFERENCES `databasestorage` (`databaseID`))